# How to upload large amounts of stopwords into AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Is it possible to upload a `stopwords.txt` onto AWS Elasticsearch and specify it as a path by stop token filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using aws elasticsearch, the only option to do this is using the elasticsearch rest APIs.

To import large data sets, you can use the bulk API.

Comment: Can you provide some example to know how exactly to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You can now upload "packages" to AWS Elasticsearch service, which lets you add custom lists of stopwords etc. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/custom-packages.html

---

No, it isn't possible to upload a `stopwords.txt` file to the hosted AWS Elasticsearch service.

What you will have to do is specify the stopwords in a custom analyzer. More details on how to do that can be found in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html).

The official documentation then says to "close and reopen" the index, but again, AWS Elasticsearch doesn't allow that, so you will then have to reindex.

Example:

**1. Create an index with your stopwords listed inline within a custom analyzer, e.g.**

```
    PUT /my_new_index
    {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "english_analyzer": {
              "type": "english", 
              "stopwords": "['a', 'the', 'they', 'and']" 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**2. Reindex**

```
    POST _reindex
    {
      "source": {
        "index": "my_index"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "my_new_index"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by setting `stopwords_path` while defining your stop token filter.

> **stopwords_path** => A path (either relative to config location, or
>   absolute) to a stopwords file configuration. Each stop word should be
>   in its own "line" (separated by a line break). The file must be UTF-8
>   encoded.

Here is how I did it.

1. Copied stopwords.txt file in the `config` folder of my elasticsearch home path.
2. Created a custom token filter with the path set in `stopwords_path`

   `PUT /testindex
   {
     "settings": {
       "analysis": {
         "filter": {
           "teststopper": {
             "type": "stop",
             "stopwords_path": "stopwords.txt"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }`
3. Verified if the filter was working as expected with `_analyze` API.

   `GET testindex/_analyze
   {
     "tokenizer" : "standard",
     "token_filters" : ["teststopper"],
     "text" : "this is a text to test the stop filter",
     "explain" : true,
     "attributes" : ["keyword"] 
   }`
4. The tokens 'a', 'an', 'the', 'to', 'is' were filtered out since I had added them in config/stopwords.txt file.

For more info:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/_explain_analyze.html

Comment: You cannot access AWS elasticsearch installation. So although this solution is valid, but it is not applicable for the question in context.

Comment: I do use Amazon services for elasticsearch but not AWS ElasticSearch but normal EC2 instances with ElasticSearch installed in them. So my answer was based on that. Thanks for the info Yeshodhan!